# Rolify's role, I can only add a role in the terminal, but I can't add it from the view side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles, rolify

I can added role with terminal, but I can't add it from the view side.
I can added role for PostUser model with terminal:

```
PostUser.first.add_role :admin
PostUser.first.has_role? :admin
=> true;
```

I tried to add this from the view side:

`routes.rb` file:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :post_users
end
```

`post_user.rb` model file:

```
class PostUser < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  belongs_to :post

  after_create :assign_default_role

   def assign_default_role
     self.add_role(:newuser) if self.roles.blank?
   end
end
```

add_role of post_user.rb model file not working!

`post.rb` model file:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
   resourcify

   belongs_to :user
   has_many :post_users, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`user.rb` model file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
   resourcify

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
   has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I also tried `resourcify` on `post.rb` and `user.rb` but it doesn't work.

What I added from the form didn't work either. `edit` file:

```
<%= form_with(model: [post, post_user]) do |form|%>
   <%= form.collection_check_boxes :role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you confirm that when you add role to the `PostUser` in console  also add that role in to database?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you give me more information?

Comment: Try this commands in rails console and share the result please:  `user = PostUser.first` , `user.add_role(:admin)`  ,  `user.has_role?(:admin)`  ,  `user.reload`  ,  `user.has_role?(:admin)`

Comment: `user.add_role(:admin)`, followed by `user.has_role?(:admin)` returns `true`, and `user.reload` after `user.has_role?(:admin)` returns `true` returns

Comment: do you get any error when creating new `PostUser`?

Comment: Check your controller if you have permitted `role_ids: []` in params

Comment: No error, just `:newuser` role is not added to it, it remains without role. Then I add a role to it again in the terminal.